# collapse buttom for specific id bootstrap 3 on angular 6

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6

I'm trying to show a specific text using a collapse button in bootstrap 3 and angular 6 (according to these instructions - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/collapse#accessibility).

The code I'm using is this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="collapse.show()"
        aria-controls="collapseManual1">Show content
</button>

<hr>
<div id="collapseManual1" #collapse="bs-collapse" [collapse]="!isOpen"
     class="card card-block card-header">
  <div class="well well-lg">Some content1</div>
</div>
<div id="collapseManual2" #collapse="bs-collapse" [collapse]="!isOpen"
     class="card card-block card-header">
  <div class="well well-lg">Some content2</div>
</div>
```

I wrote it to see if I can somehow collapse the first div but it doesn't work, the code only collapse the second div. aria-controls doesn't effect anything. It seems that the last element that has #collapse="bs-collapse" is what get shown.

I also tried to add data-target:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="collapse.show()" data-target="#collapseManual1" aria-controls="collapseManual1">Show content
</button>
```

and href:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="collapse.show()" href="#collapseManual1" aria-controls="collapseManual1">Show content
</button>
```

But results were the same.

How can I make the collapse.show() to work on a specific id?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the same template reference variable `#collapse` to both of your divs

Try using differents vars like `#collapseone` and `#collapsetwo`
Otherwise i think they are conflicting themself